# Compare today's date to a column and highlight the cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell-formatting

In my winform app , there is a column called "Next_Calibration_On"(in the format "dd-MM-yyyy") with which i have to compare today date if it is less than it then i want highlight the cell in the datagrid view in red .
Fr this i have the below code :

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currentToday = (DateTime)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Next_Calibration_On"].Value;

        if (currentToday <= DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; //Font Color
            e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red; //Selection Font color
        }
```

However this is showing the error message as  below:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Column named Next_Calibration_On cannot be found.Parameter name: columnName'
```

But i do have column in my table ..how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `System.ArgumentException:` says you don’t. Who should we believe? Can you show to column definitions? Or the table you are binding to the grid?

Comment: Hi JohnG i have edited my question with the picture , please ask me if anything more details is needed.

Comment: How are you getting the data from the table to the grid? Are you setting a data source?

Comment: Yes ..i have binding source(.accdb) ..i have updated my question with another image which fulfils all the data source related info.

Comment: Edit the “Next_Calibration_On” column and look at its properties. Your pictures do not show this column. I am confident it may well be there; however, you need to look at its properties and see if it may have a different name. Show the properties of the column in question.

Comment: Added the image which shows the properties , but i think i found the error with your help ..however i'll wait for your reply.

Comment: Look at the name above column type...!

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing the underlying `DataTable` and the `DataGridView`. Column names do not propagate from one to the other. Those names are independent.

Comment: While `DateTime.Now.Date` is not wrong per se, `DateTime.Today` is more correct.

Comment: Yes the Problem is now solved thank you so much for your help ..And @jmcilhinney yes i have made the correction as you told ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't edit your cells. Tell your DataGridView where to fetch its data

Don't put the data directly in the DataGridView, tell it where to fetch its data, and how to display the fetched data. This separates your data from how it is displayed. Whenever you decide to display it differently you don't have to change your original data.

You can see how this separation between data and display is done in a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet data can be shown as a collection of cells layed out in columns and rows, and displaying textual representation of the values in the cells.

Another method to show the same data would be in a graph: even though the display is entirely different than a collection of cells, the data behind is the same.

Same data, differently displayed.

In winforms you have the same separations with all Controls that show sequences of data: ListBox, ListView, DataGridView, Chart, etc.

All these classes offer the possibility to directly add the data to the component, but they also have a property `DataSource`.

If you assign a sequence to the DataSource, something like a List or Array, the Data is displayed. other properties decide how each element of the DataSource must be displayed.

In a DataGridView the DataGridViewColumns define which property of each row must be displayed, and how they must be displayed.

In its most easy form:

Suppose you have a class Customer:

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
    public string PhoneNr {get; set;}
};
```

Suppose you also have a DataGridView that shows only the Id and Name of Customers

```
DataGridViewColumn columnCustomerId = new DateGridViewColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = nameof(Customer.Id),
    ValueType = typeof(int),
};
DataGridViewColumn columnCustomerName = new DateGridViewColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = nameof(Customer.Name),
    ValueType = typeof(string),
};
DataGridView customersDataGridView = new DataGridView(...) {...}
customersDataGridView.Columns.Add(columnCustomerId);
customersDataGridView.Columns.Add(columnCustomerName);
```

Now to show Customers:

```
List<Customer> customers = FetchCustomers(...);
customersDataGridview.DataSource = customers;
```

This is enough to show the customer's Id and Name. If you also want to show the Telephone numbers, just add a Column. You don't have to change your original data.

Similarly if you want to format the cells of certain customers differently: this has no influence on your original customer collection. Only the Display changes.

### Side Remark

Although the above works, you still have problems if operators edit the displayed data. If you want to automatically update changes made by operators, do not put the data in a List, but in a [System.ComponentModel.BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netcore-3.1):

```
BindingList<Customer> customers = new BindingList<Customer>(FetchCustomers(...));
customerDataGridView.DataSource = customers;
```

Now if the operator adds / removes / changes Customers from the DataGridView, they are automatically updated in the BindingList.

And a handy tip: if you want automatic sorting by clicking on the column header, and if you want easy filtering: "show only Customers who live in 'Amsterdam'" without having to change the Customers list, consider to use [Nuget package BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView)

```
BindingListView<Customer> customers = new BindingListView<Customer>(FetchCustomers(...));
customerDataGridView.DataSource = customers;
```

And presto: you've got sortable columns; editable customers. Filtering is easy:

```
// show only Amsterdam customers:
customers.ApplyFilter( customer => customer.Address.City == "Amsterdam");
```

Even though you don't show the City of the customer in the DataGridView, you can easily filter on it.

By the way: did you notice how easy I switched from DataSource without even changing my DataGridView? This is because I separated the display from the source data.

### Back to your question

You want to change the layout of the cells in column NextCalibration. Every Cell with a value higher than xxx should be Red.

The layout of a cell is done in a [DataGridViewCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle?view=netcore-3.1). If your Cell doesn't have its own CellStyle, it uses the CellStyle of the DataGridViewColumn.

You want to change the cell style whenever the value of the displayed property meets some requirement. In this case: foreground color red if it is less than today's date, otherwise the default value. Make a Clone of the default cell style of the column.

```
DataGridViewColumn columnNextCalibration = ...
DataGridViewCellStyle specialCellStyle = (DataGridViewCellStyle)columnNextCalibration
    .CellTemplate
    .CellStyle
    .Clone();
```

If your column has no special style (it is null), use the InheritedStyle.

```
// adjust the CellStyle to the style it should have when the value meets the requirements
specialCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
// if desired: change the Font, the fontSize, or the BackColor, the frame whatever!
```

You want to select either the default CellStyle (null) or this special cell style, depending on the displayed DateTime value:

Now that you have a special CellStyle wait until the displayed value changes:

```
this.customersDataGridView.CellValueChanges += OnCellValueChanged;

private void OnCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    // is the changed cell from my column in my DataGridView?
    if (Object.ReferencEquals(sender, customersDataGridView)
    && e.ColumnIndex == columnNextCalibation.DisplayIndex)
    {
        DataGridViewCell changedCell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Column[e.ColumnIndex];
        DateTime cellValue = (DateTime)cell.Value;
        DateTime today = ...
        if (cellValue < today)
        {
            // use the special CellStyle:
            changedCell.CellStyle = specialCellStyle;
        }
        else
        {
            // use the default CellStyle of the column, not a special one for this cell
            changedCell.CellStyle = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed suggestion..it really helped me a lot